# Identifying State Parks in the PAD-US dataset (Protected Areas Database)

Tags: data, query, united-states

I'm looking to map "State Parks," and I found this phenomenal, but complex database. Has anyone ever worked with the PAD datasets before? (or know any easier way to map State Parks?)

In the PAD download there are several included shapefiles, including: `fee`, `easement`, `marine`, `proclamation`, and `designation`. It sounds like there is overlap in the datasets. So far my best guess is to use the `fee` shapefile, filtering on `access='open access'` and `designation='state historic or cultural areas' or 'state park' or 'state recreation area'`. But I'm just not 100% sure if I've gotten everything this way. The total number of features returned is 8,065, which is close to the number noted at [stateparks.org](https://www.stateparks.org/about-us/state-park-facts/) (8,565 for FY 2017), but it's still 500 features short. When I add in `designation='state other or unknown'` it brings the total up to 8,447. Although I suppose this number could have (and likely did) go down since the latest release of the data. **Still, it would be nice to know the exact query I should be using.**

**PAD-US Main Page**
https://www.usgs.gov/news/mapping-public-lands-united-states

**Data Download***
https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/science-analytics-and-synthesis/gap/science/pad-us-data-download?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects

*I downloaded the *"national shapefile"*

I'm aware of all the following helpful documentation already:

**Data Structure and Attributes** 
http://www.protectedlands.net/pad-us-data-structure-attributes/

**Metadata XML**
https://data.usgs.gov/metadata/Science_Analytics_and_Synthesis/5b030c7ae4b0da30c1c1d6de.xml

**PAD-US Data Manual:**
https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/science-analytics-and-synthesis/gap/pad-us-data-manual

**Disclaimer:**
“Any use of PAD-US data for showing recreational lands must be careful to show only those lands that have fee ownership and designations that are appropriate to recreational use – the PAD-US ‘Access’ attribute is a key tool for these applications, defining what is Open, Restricted/Permitted, and Closed for public access.”

**Citation**
U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) Gap Analysis Project (GAP), 2018, Protected Areas Database of the United States (PAD-US): U.S. Geological Survey data release, https://doi.org/10.5066/P955KPLE.

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask about its data model may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thank you! I will

Comment: Posted to: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/17481/identifying-state-parks-in-the-pad-us-dataset-protected-areas-database